# How to add "Short by Date" when loading category tab slider on Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using Bxslider v4.0 on my magento theme for category tab slider but product has been show short by product ID.

What I want to do is get the items in order by their new from date, so that I have the newest first.

And here is the slider code maybe you help this for you.
app/code/local/magentothem

```
function getProductCate($id = NULL) {
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $json_products = array();
    //load the category's products as a collection
    $_productCollection = $product->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'special_price'))
            ->addCategoryFilter($_category);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
    $productLimits = $this->getProductsCount();
    if(!$productLimits) $productLimits = 10;
    $_productCollection->setPageSize($productLimits);
    $_productCollection->load();
    return $_productCollection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the line `$_productCollection->load();`, add:

```
$_productCollection ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

If the field you want to sort by is not `created_at`, replace it by the proper name (not sure if I understood the problem)